# xcode6 linker failure (with cuppunit)

Tags: linker, xcode6, xcode6.1, cppunit

I am trying to get cupping working with xcode6, and I got this error:

> ld: library not found for -lcppunit-1.12.1.0.0
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

after searching with Google, I got a tip : `add -force_ld.` However, another error came up.

> ld: file not found: -lcppunit-1.12.1.0.0
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The program is written entirely in C ++?